# Address Django translation messages using variables

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, rails-i18n, django-i18n

Is there a way to set translation messages parametrically in Django?
For example, when I need to traslate a message in a template, I always need to write the whole text:

```
<h1>{% trans "Hello World" %}</h1>
```

Instead, I'm wondering if there is something that allows to use variables, something similar to Ruby on Rails:

```
<h1><%= t :hello_world %></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [`trans` template tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) you can pass a variable in the same way you pass a string literal:

```
<h1>{% trans myvar %}</h1>
```

Of course that variable need to be available in the template context

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a middleware where all variables are saved?

Comment: I would probably suggest a context processor for that purpose: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: Good idea! But I need to create an efficient system to load only the needed vars into the template. Otherwise the context processor will load the whole set of messages..